# How to get creation DateTime of file from very long path?

Tags: c#, datetime, kernel32, interopservices, safehandle

I have file paths which are very long, so can be handled only using `SafeFileHandle`.
Want to get creation datetime.
When tried getting millies and then converted in `DateTime` then it is 1600 years less.

**Code:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetFileTime(SafeFileHandle hFile, ref long lpCreationTime, ref long lpLastAccessTime, ref long lpLastWriteTime);

void fnc(String file){
    var filePath = @"\\?\" + file;
    var fileObj = CreateFile(filePath, Constants.SafeFile.GENERIC_READ, 0, IntPtr.Zero, Constants.SafeFile.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    long millies = 0, l1 = 0, l2 = 0;

    if(GetFileTime(fileObj, ref millies, ref l1, ref l2))
    {
        DateTime creationTime = new DateTime(millies, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Above `creationTime` is 1600 years less. Instead of year 2019, its 0419.

Then I had to do this

```
        DateTime creationTime = new DateTime(millies, DateTimeKind.Local).AddYears(1600);
    }
}
```

Above `creationTime` is correct as I have added 1600 years.

What makes date 1600 years less?
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The FILETIME structure returned by GetFileTime returns the number of 100 nanosecond intervals starting from January 1st 1601: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime

Comment: I believe you can use DateTime.FromFileTime() to convert safely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FILETIME structure returned by GetFileTime returns the number of 100 nanosecond intervals starting from January 1st 1601. You can see the documentation for this here: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime)

Rather than adding 1600 years there is a built in .net function that converts for you - `DateTime.FromFileTime()`. In your example the code would be:

```cs
if (GetFileTime(fileObj, ref millies, ref l1, ref l2))
{
    DateTime creationTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(millies);
}
```

I would also change the variable name from `millies` as that is a bit misleading (GetFileTime does not return milliseconds).

Comment: Thanks @theduck, even I was confused with name ```millies```, I could have change it to something like```ticks```. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Depends a bit on your naming conventions I guess but creationTimeInTicks?

Comment: That make sense!

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely by design when working with file times.

The basis for the returned file time is a counter from 01/01/1601:

> A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1,
>   1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Reference the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times).

Comment: Thanks @Martin. So I guess in my case adding 1600 years is the way, right?